# Fluid tag for displaying GitHub Gists with noscript tags in a Jekyll post

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

A while back I wrote a [Fluid tag for Jekyll](http://brandontilley.com/2011/01/31/gist-tag-for-jekyll.html) that inserts the contents of a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/) into the content of the page in `<noscript>` tags for RSS readers. I've noticed a couple things I'm not happy with since posting it, but I am interested in the critique it will generate here on Stack Exchange!

(Obviously, some of the internals regarding methods required to make Liquid tags work (such as the parameters to `initialize` and having a `render` method) aren't negotiable, but you get the idea.)

```
require 'digest/md5'
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'

module Jekyll
  class GistTag < Liquid::Tag
    def initialize(tag_name, text, token)
      super
      @text         = text
      @cache        = true
      @cache_folder = File.expand_path "../_gist_cache", File.dirname(__FILE__)
    end

    def render(context)
      return "" unless @text =~ /([\d]*) (.*)/

      gist, file = $1.strip, $2.strip
      script_url = "https://gist.github.com/#{gist}.js?file=#{file}"

      code       = get_cached_gist(gist, file) || get_gist_from_web(gist, file)
      code       = code.gsub "<", "&lt;"
      string     = "<script src='#{script_url}'></script>"
      string    += "<noscript><pre><code>#{code}</code></pre></noscript>"
      return string
    end

    def get_gist_url_for(gist, file)
      "https://gist.github.com/raw/#{gist}/#{file}"
    end

    def cache_gist(gist, file, data)
      file = get_cache_file_for gist, file
      File.open(file, "w+") do |f|
        f.write(data)
      end
    end

    def get_cached_gist(gist, file)
      return nil if @cache == false
      file = get_cache_file_for gist, file
      return nil unless File.exist?(file)
      return File.new(file).read
    end

    def get_cache_file_for(gist, file)
      bad_chars = /[^a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.]/
      gist      = gist.gsub bad_chars, ''
      file      = file.gsub bad_chars, ''
      md5       = Digest::MD5.hexdigest "#{gist}-#{file}"
      File.join @cache_folder, "#{gist}-#{file}-#{md5}.cache"
    end

    def get_gist_from_web(gist, file)
      gist_url          = get_gist_url_for(gist, file)
      raw_uri           = URI.parse(gist_url)
      https             = Net::HTTP.new(raw_uri.host, raw_uri.port)
      https.use_ssl     = true
      https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
      request           = Net::HTTP::Get.new(raw_uri.request_uri)
      data              = https.request(request)
      data              = data.body
      cache_gist(gist, file, data) unless @cache == false
      data
    end
  end

  class GistTagNoCache < GistTag
    def initialize(tag_name, text, token)
      super
      @cache = false
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('gist', Jekyll::GistTag)
Liquid::Template.register_tag('gistnocache', Jekyll::GistTagNoCache)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of mostly minor notes and improvements:

```
return "" unless @text =~ /([\d]*) (.*)/
gist, file = $1.strip, $2.strip
```

I generally try to avoid magic variables where ever possible. Using `match` and the resulting `MatchData` object tends to be less error prone.

---

```
code       = code.gsub "<", "&lt;"
```

Is there a reason you only escape `<` characters? Unless I'm missing something, it seems preferable to use `CGI.escapeHTML` instead.

---

```
return string
```

It seems inconsistent to me that in some methods you have a `return` statement on the last line and in others you do not. I would always leave out the `return` statement on the last line as it is unnecessary.

---

```
return nil if @cache == false
```

It is pretty unidiomatic to use `==` with boolean literals - usually one would just negate the boolean instead of comparing to `false`. `if !@cache` or better `unless @cache` will read more natural to most people than `if @cache == false`.

---

```
File.new(file).read
```

You should never use `File.new` without storing its return value somewhere and then later calling `close` on it. As a matter of fact in most cases you should not use `File.new` at all, but rather `File.open` with a block, which closes the file automatically when the block's end is reached. The way you're doing it the file handle will remain open until the `File` object is garbage collected, which may be a while. This is a bad practice and can lead to subtle problems.

However in this case you don't even need `File.open` as there is already a method which does exactly what you need: `File.read(file)`.

---

```
gist.gsub! /[^a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.]/, ''
```

You don't need to escape `.` as it has no special meaning inside brackets.

---

```
cache_gist(gist, file, data) unless @cache == false
```

This would really be a lot more readable without the explicit comparison and the double negation:

```
cache_gist(gist, file, data) if @cache
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I saw your comment on magic variables in another of your answers, and with good points; you're right about the `return`s, it's quite inconsistent (is there a better/more idiomatic way of handling the return branches in `get_cached_gist`?); and `File.new(file).read` was an embarrassing bug introduced from getting rid of the even worse `File.new(file).readlines.join`, but when I "fixed" it I forgot to get rid of the call to `new`!

Comment: As for the boolean check, I think I just have a badly named boolean; changing it to `@caching_enabled` or similar makes the "positive" match much more readable in English. Thanks again for all the tips!

Comment: @BinaryMuse: "is there a better/more idiomatic way of handling the return branches in `get_cached_gist`?" No, the way you did it seems fine.

Comment: Great, thanks again. I'm quite happy with [the refactored code](https://gist.github.com/803483#file_gist_tag.rb).